# Получить высоту окна при открытой клавиатуре JS

Tags: javascript

Не могу определить на мобильном устройстве высоту окна при открытой клавиатуре.
Пробовал через window.screen.height и подобное, но ничего не меняется.
Как решить проблему?

Comment: Пробовали создать элемент с `position: absolute; inset: 0;` и проверить его размеры?

Comment: @UserTest013 нет, но пробовал через width: 100%|100vh - результата нет. как будто браузер считает клавиатуру, как часть элементов DOM и отдаёт 100% высоту экрана, но не правильный размер окна браузера

Comment: как я вычитал, клавиатура открывается поверх окна и никак не влияет на размер окна. нужно как-то узнать высоту клавиатуры или что-то в этом роде